# Vaadin: Dynamically change a textfield's background color

Tags: java, vaadin

How does one dynamically change a textfield's visual properties, say background color?

An example might be during a validation to modify the background color dependent on the value entered.

Comment: Which vaadin version are you using ?

Answer (score 5):

In your war (this will be inside WebContent if you are using ecilpse) have a file in this path VAADIN/themes/customrunno/styles.css (asuming you are using runno as your theme)

With this content:

```
@import url(../runo/styles.css);

.my_bg_style {
     background: #99EE6B;  
}
```

In your init method:

```
setTheme("customruno"); // same as the folder folder under VAADIN/themes
```

change your textfield background:

```
textField.addStyleName("my_bg_style"); // same as in styles.css
```

to remove the style just do:

```
textField.removeStyleName("my_bg_style");
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the sample

```css
.v-textfield-dashing     
{    
    border:     thin dashed;    
    background: white; /* Has shading image by default */    
}
```

Detailed information you will get on this link.
https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.textfield.html

And if you want to change textfield color dynamically then you will get content on below link
https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Dynamically%20injecting%20CSS

Comment: Instead of injecting CSS, you could use addStyleName() to add another CSS class or removeStyleName() to remove it